# How to perform exclusive lock on a transaction so that other transaction can't access(read, write) same table (In Sequelize)?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, concurrency, sequelize.js

I am having a nodejs program which uses **sequelize** to create tables and insert data based on it.

Now, in future we are going to have multiple instances of the program and so we don't want multiple instances to read from the table during program startup so that only one instance can do the setup thing if required and other instance shouldn't get 'any access' to the table until the first instance has completed it's work.

My requirement is specifically that once a transaction acquires lock on a table, other transaction **shouldn't be able to read, write** from that table unless first one has completed it's work. How can I do this using **sequelize transaction**?

*NOTE: I don't want to use Raw queries in sequelize. As I already have transaction setup, in the same transaction want to find some way to do some config so this can be achieved.*

Comment: For me, it looks like you're trying to use the incorrect tool to achieve this goal: initialize the first instance and other instances should wait for it. I suppose you need some synchronization tool/package/service. Or you can simply run other instances from the first one

Comment: Actually, the same code will be running in different instances of the application. Which will run as soon as I will start the application.

Comment: You definitely have the main instance and child instances that should wait until the main one will finish some initialization. And only after that they should do the same initialization. Did I get it correct?

Comment: I am checking in a table if something needs to be added in a db table. If it's yes then I add it. Now let's say I have 2 instances of the application which gets spin up at the same time. How should I protect the second instance to do the same task? Because in case both instance reads from table and get a response "Yes" then both will insert data into required db table. That's the reason I asked this question (Particularly in case of sequelize transaction). Can you help?

Comment: I'm sure it can be solved much easier by adding some parameter in a config and setting it to true only for the main instance and using it to check if there is a need to add some records.

Comment: I am using kubernetes so that won't work.

Comment: Can't it run different instances with different configs? Very disappointing. Anyway it's not a good idea to lock a table to it like a mutex. PostgreSQL has different types of locks and you can indicate some of them in Sequelize queries if that's what you want

Comment: Yes correct, that's what I am looking for. "How to do that locking of table in sequelize transaction" - As I already have a transaction, now I just want to have a lock so other transactions can't access the same table :)

Comment: Then try to indicate both `transaction` and `lock` options on `findAll` (or whatever you use to read records) and of course you need the correct isolation level for the transaction

Comment: Yes now you got exactly what I am looking for. I would be obliged if someone can provide the way of doing this in findAll. I have already included transaction and lock: true options, and have set islolation level to "serializable" but still couldn't do it, that's why opened this issue. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: + currently my other transaction is able to read even if lock is done. That's the problem I am facing.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try to indicate different lock types instead of `true`?

Comment: Nope, while creating transaction, I have just set the isolation level as Serializable. According to the docs that should do the job right? I mean it mentioned that by doing this no other transaction could interfere in case serializable isolation type is done while creating the transaction

Comment: Nonetheless, an you try to indicate different lock types in the query itself?

Comment: Sure, I will try and update. One thing I want to confirm - if while creating transaction I am defining isolation level then that should take care of the concurrent transactions? I mean a separate lock on query shouldn't be ideally required in that case right?